# Configure composer to use class names with prefixes

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a folder structure like this:

```sh
Root-Folder/backend/user/class-user.php
Root-Folder/backend/profile/class-profile.php
Root-Folder/backend/login.php
```

Sample `class-user.php` content:

```php
namespace myapp\user;
class User{
....
}
```

In my composer.json:

```
...
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "myapp\\": "backend/"
        }
    },
...
```

But this way the files are not included because they have a `class-` prefix in the file name. If I change the file names to `user.php` and `profile.php`, they work.

How can I configure composer to include `class-user.php` too?

Comment: You should refactor your file names to match the class names (case sensitivity matters). That's generally how its done.

Comment: Is there any way I can include class prefix? WordPress Coding standards require the file names to have `class` in them. So `Class User` should be named `class-user.php`

Comment: You can use the `files` directive to list the list explicitly: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-autoload-classes-with-composer-in-php--cms-35649

Comment: What do you mean by "not included"? Where's the code to do that? Is there any error message given?

Comment: You could possibly create symlinks (Profile.php -> class-profile.php) automatically during the build/deployment process.

Comment: _WordPress Coding standards require the file names to have `class` in them._ Doesn’t mean _you_ have to. It’s a standard. And it goes against PSR namespacing standards that Composer follows.

Answer (score 1):

PSR-4 requires classes names to be the same as file name that contains it.
In this case you need to use "classmap" directive instead of PSR-4

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["backend"]
    }
}
```